# AWS Batch S3 lambda job response produces error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, batch-processing

I have a problem running S3 batch job. I contacted AWS support on this issue already but they didn't answer anything meaningful, so Stackoverflow is my only hope to resolve this :)

I need to copy a big amount (up 10 10000) files from one location to another. Initially I was going to use S3 Batch Copy operation, but the problem with it is that it doesn't let me change output path, and this aspect is critical, as I'm gathering files from different locations to one for further processing in Athena.

So after a while of googling I ended up using S3 Batch Lambda operation, where I'm just making s3 copy object request for each entry. It works nice and fast, but the problem is that I'm receiving error in report for each entry because of incorrect json returned by lambda. I'm returning response json based on [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-s3-batch.html). It's not for c#, but that's the only reference I was able to find. So my json looks like this:

```
{
    "invocationSchemaVersion": "1.0",
    "invocationId": "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",
    "treatMissingKeysAs": "PermanentFailure",
    "results": [
        {
            "taskId": "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",
            "resultCode": "Succeeded",
            "resultString": "asdasdasd"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the error I'm receiving in report is:

> Invalid JSON returned in Lambda payload: "{"invocationSchemaVersion":"1.0","invocationId":"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

The first thing that caught my eye is that invocation id and task id are very long, much longer than in example, and even in error message they get truncated. But here's the object structure I'm receiving on lambda input and I'm using Invocation id and Task id correspondingly:

```
public class S3BatchEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("invocationSchemaVersion")]
    public string InvocationSchemaVersion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("invocationId")]
    public string InvocationId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("job")]
    public Job Job { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tasks")]
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    [JsonProperty("taskId")]
    public string TaskId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("s3BucketArn")]
    public string S3BucketArn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("s3Key")]
    public string S3Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("s3VersionId")]
    public object S3VersionId { get; set; }
}
```

So I actually have several questions on that:

1. What am I doing wrong in terms of forming response?
2. I had to log incoming json and create corresponding types by myself, and also I'm forming response as anonymous object manually. Are there existing types in .Net SDK for these? I couldn't find any reference.

Also, maybe there is some other way of doing what I need? Maybe there's a way to run batch s3 copy with dynamic output? Or I was thinking about running bunch of lambdas manually, but I'm not sure how to balance the amount of records processed by each like batch job does. To make it clear, the crucial for my task is timing (with s3 batch copy job it takes couple seconds to copy 7k files 10-50 Mb each) and that tasks are being run remotely on s3 side, because the whole process is initiated from machine with very limited resources and such amount of tasks is literally killing it or slowing the whole operation up to 10 minutes if I'm throttling the number of concurrent tasks.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: They seem to be base64-encoded and, as you suggest, much longer than expected. They don't actually seem to be valid IDs at all. Do you have control of the source that's populating these IDs?

Comment: @jarmod, no, I don't, and that's the thing. That's what S3 Batch job giving my lambda on input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so through the blood, sweat and tears I figured what was wrong. It appears that these huge ids are totally fine, you just have to return object instead of string. So, in case somebody will get into the same problem, the final attempt that worked is:

```
    return new
    {
        invocationSchemaVersion = s3Event.InvocationSchemaVersion,
        invocationId = s3Event.InvocationId,
        treatMissingKeysAs = "PermanentFailure",
        results = new[]
        {
            new
            {
                taskId = s3Event.Tasks[0].TaskId,
                resultCode = "Succeeded",
                resultString = "Succeeded"
            }
        }
            
           
    };
```

also make sure properties are in CamelCase, it will fail otherwise.

Comment: I'm receiving the same error. But I have my lambda function in Python. In Python, the event request is a dictionary, so there is not concept of an object. Any ideas what do I need to change in Python?